# How to use the extracted webpack's manifest?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler, manifest

In Webpack's documentation says the you can extract the manifest logic in to a seperate file usiong the WebpackManifestPlugin.

What i dont understand is what i need this manifest for? I can edit it? If yes then how do i read it?

The docs dont say anything about crucial about the manifest [Manifest](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#the-manifest)

Comment: If you don't know you need the manifest, then you don't need it...

Comment: @AKX Well i have to understand the manifest first to see if i need it or not

Comment: What would you think you'd need it for? Do you need to programmatically know how source modules map to chunks and bundles for some reason? If you don't, you don't need the manifest. Either way, the [usage example](https://github.com/shellscape/webpack-manifest-plugin#usage) for the plugin shows the format.

Comment: @AKX This link shows how to export manifest. If i want to change the manifest (for reasons) how to i import it?

Comment: I don't think you can import it into Webpack as-is. Why would you want to do that?